# Python Django get distinct queryset by month from a DateField

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('p', 'P'),
        ('c', 'C'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TRANSACTION_TYPE_CHOICES, default='c')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_wallet')
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    amount = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I am a fresher in `Python django` and have a little knowledge in `Django Rest Framework`.

I have a model like above and I want to filter the date field by month and  get distinct queryset by month.....Is there any default way to do this...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [TruncMonth](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth) with [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations)

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    month=TruncMonth('date')
).filter(month=YOURVALUE).values('month').distinct()
```

or if you need only filter date by month with distinct you can use [__month](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#month) option

```
MyModel.objects.filter(date__month=YOURVALUE).distinct()
```

**Older django**
you can use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra), example for postgres

```
MyModel.objects.extra(
    select={'month': "EXTRACT(month FROM date)"},
    where=["EXTRACT(month FROM date)=%s"],
    params=[5]
    # CHANGE 5 on you value
    ).values('month').distinct()
```

Comment: from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
ImportError: cannot import name TruncMonth

Comment: what django version do you use?

Comment: I am using Django 1.9.12

Comment: other time if you use not last version it will be good to add version and database to the question, good if you edit your question now, and please check the last solution, thank you.

Comment: does the solution help you? if yes you should apply it, for other people who will seach the same.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

`MyModel.object.values('col1','col2',...,'date').distinct('date')`

OR try this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
MyModel.objects
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date'))  # Truncate to month and add to select list
    .values('month')                          # Group By month
    .annotate(c=Count('id'))                  # Select the count of the grouping
    .values('month', 'c')                     # (might be redundant, haven't tested) select month and count
```

Comment: I want to distinct the queryset  from DateField by month

Comment: Please check update answer, this may work not tested !!.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare good copy) you need add import `Count` and change the line break after `objects` and i don think about group by month will work